# Ignore click on transparent part of the ImageView

Tags: android, imageview

I have 2 ImageViews which overlap each other, both contain an image with some transparent parts (PNG).
When I click in the transparent part of the imageView, the eventListener is called for this imageView. I would like the call the listener only when a non-transparent part is clicked!
This way it becomes possible to click 'through' the imageView and possibly call the listener of the imageView which is behind.

Comment: Can you provide more info or some example code :D ?

Comment: Put your image and xml source

Comment: There is no code yet. :) xml is very simple, just on FrameLayout with 2 ImageViews inside of it. Both ImageViews are match_parent width and height.

Answer (score 3):

Take imageview and bind it with view, set drawing cache enable true
**ImageView:**

```
ImageView imgView= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.color_blue);
imgView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
imgView.setOnTouchListener(changeColorListener);
```

**OnTouchListener of Imageview:**

```
private OnTouchListener changeColorListener = new OnTouchListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getDrawingCache());
        int color = bmp.getPixel((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
        if (color == Color.TRANSPARENT)
            return false;
        else {
            //click portion without transparent color
            return true;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: You can also test original Image considering scale matrix (if any) that ImageView applies to your bitmap. It is a little bit harder but faster.

Comment: @Leonidos, Can you please explain me in details or can you please give me example for the same ?